# Website on google taking time to reach ON ubuntu with https

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, google-cloud-platform

Website on google taking time to reach ON ubuntu with https.

Receiving pings at following frequency:

```
icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=3.59 ms
icmp_seq=6 ttl=59 time=3.74 ms
icmp_seq=8 ttl=59 time=3.71 ms
icmp_seq=7 ttl=59 time=3.11 ms
icmp_seq=9 ttl=59 time=5.93 ms
```

But when I do telnet with port **443** then sometimes it works well. But sometimes it takes more than 12 seconds to respond..(**Apache** level I'm receiving very late hits).

Comment: Its just one server hosted with db (connected with private ip)...so no concept of load balancing.

Simple page with no db connection is taking longer to load sometimes

Answer (score 0):

The most common latency issue while using GCP is the [region/zone](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection#factors_to_consider_when_selecting_regions) selection, you can verify which ones have the lowest latency [here](https://itm.cloud.com/google-reports/). At the moment there is no issue with networking according to Google [Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) You can also take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/5-steps-to-better-gcp-network-performance?hl=ml) article to review some suggestions on how to have better network performance. You can try to use Network Intelligence to perform a [connectivity test](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests#running-conn-test) to your network and verify the results you observe in your VM instance pings and telnet responses.

Answer (score 0):

Start a packet capture on the system from which you are trying to telnet to port 443:

tcpdump -n -w .pcap -i  -s 96 'port 442'

and then do your:

telnet  443

and then once you have captured one of these 12 second responses take a look at the capture:

tcpdump -n -r .pcap | less

and I wouldn't be surprised if you were to see the connection-establishment packets (aka "SYN" segments - TCP packets are "segments" and a SYNchronize segment is used to initial a connection) being retransmitted.  A TCP SYN segment will have a "flags" field showing "[S]" .
You would expect to see a SYN|ACK(nowledgement) segment in the trace shortly after the SYN.  A SYN|ACK will have a flags of "[S.]"  (the "dot" saying the ACK flag is set in the segment)

The -n option on the command line will mean that hosts will be shown by their IP addresses rather than trying to find their names.   The port number is appended to the IPs.

To see if a SYN was retransmitted, you want to match the ipaddress.port entries, along with the flags and the initial sequence number.  There will be a "seq" field in the output.

Here is an example of what it looks like trying to connect to a destination which never responds:

```
$ tcpdump -n -r foo.pcap
reading from file foo.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
16:25:47.496141 IP 10.128.0.50.51034 > 1.2.3.4.443: Flags [S], seq 4180579140, win 65320, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 3681478601 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:25:48.497232 IP 10.128.0.50.51034 > 1.2.3.4.443: Flags [S], seq 4180579140, win 65320, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 3681479602 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:25:50.513267 IP 10.128.0.50.51034 > 1.2.3.4.443: Flags [S], seq 4180579140, win 65320, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 3681481618 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:25:54.641285 IP 10.128.0.50.51034 > 1.2.3.4.443: Flags [S], seq 4180579140, win 65320, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 3681485746 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:26:02.833367 IP 10.128.0.50.51034 > 1.2.3.4.443: Flags [S], seq 4180579140, win 65320, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 3681493938 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:26:18.961238 IP 10.128.0.50.51034 > 1.2.3.4.443: Flags [S], seq 4180579140, win 65320, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 3681510066 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

You can see the ipaddress.port and the flags and the "seq" previously mentioned, along with the timestamp of when that was sent.  You will see the retransmissions come 1, 2, 4, etc seconds apart as it goes.